# Removed default scene from storyboard cant rotate!\

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, orientation

So I created a universal app, when I go into my iPad storyboard and remove the only scene that was created then add something like a navigation controller, tableview controller or even a regular view controller, I can no longer rotate my application in simulator. I have made no code changes at this point. I verified that my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method hasnt changed. Is there a setting that I am missing that I have to set in the scene to allow it to rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the new controller's class to something that has `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: It is using my class ViewController which does implement that method. That is what is really weird about this.

Comment: You should add some more detail then